# Множественная запись в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

есть таблица в которой редактируются данные и кнопка, по которой это всё сохраняется.
Запрос изначально выглядел таким образом:

```
 $SQL = "UPDATE Users SET phone='$phone', name='$name', surname='$surname', second_name='$second_name', manager_comment='$manager_comment', delivery_adress='$delivery_adress', delivery_time='$delivery_time', delivery_date='$delivery_date', courier='$courier' WHERE id='$form_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);
```

Но он записывает только 1 строку.
Как перестроить запрос таким образом, чтобы он делал множественную запись по каждому id?

Comment: Запустить запрос в цикле

Comment: Чего делать ни в коем случае нельзя.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов можно

Comment: Так то и попу пальцем можно подтирать пока вас ни кто не видит. Уточню - если вы кфалифицированный программист - нельзя. А если вы сайты за три тысячи делаете - можно все в принципе. Так что вы, в какой то степени, правы.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, не надо путать квалифицированного программиста с догматиком, который где-то слышал звон, но не понял смысла :)

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, где пруффы Билли!? Ждемс пруффы... Я даже больше скажу, без цикла вы просто не сможете собрать нужный запрос для отправки, если руками собирать - это будет одно и тоже, что в ручную по запросу регистрировать пользователя, который тебе шлет анкету на почту... Или вы прочитали очередного мего, топик стартера, который сказал нельзя? Я же `супер-пупер-мего-кфалифицированный-программист`.

Comment: @And на самом деле все объясняется очень просто. Во-первых, речь здесь идет не об отсутствии цикла в принципе, а о выполнении запросов в цикле. Во-вторых, начинающих программистов, которые не освоили джойнов, действительно шпыняют за выполнение в цикле запросов SELECT. Что и имел в виду товарищ Максим. Но это, разумеется, не значит, что вообще любой случай выполнения запросов в цикле должен быть забанен, и обязательно необходимо выполнять только 1 запрос любой ценой

Comment: @Ипатьев, `JOIN`, а причем тут он? Когда речь, о сборке запроса в цикле!

Comment: @And на самом деле тут вопрос не про собрку в цикле, а про выполнение в цикле. В первом комментарии, с котрого все началось, написано не "собрать запрос в цикле", а "запустить запрос в цикле".

Comment: @Ипатьев, Окей, а как-же соединение, а после на ранее созданном соединении, отправка запросов, а не каждый раз разрыв/открытие, разрыв/открытие, нежели сбор, открытие, отправка, когда сразу отправка. в цикле.

Comment: @And я не понял этого вопроса. Но думаю что в любом случае эта дискуссия слишком  затянулась

Comment: @Ипатьев, да вы просто не понимаете, когда будет более 2х одновременных запросов, к примеру для добавки, вы скажете ах. А после скажете лучше бы цикл это сделал, нежели я буду делать это в ручку и собирать в цикле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правильно отметил DaemonHK, нет никакой проблемы запустить запрос в цикле.

Это будет простым и понятным вариантом, для его реализации не нужно "разобираться, как передать данные в виде такой таблицы". В программировании всегда следует избегать ненужного переусложнения кода на пустом месте.

А вот для подготовленных выражений, про которые тебе говорят уже в который раз, несколько запросов в цикле - это как раз очень хороший случай, чтобы их применить.

Тем более что любой хитровыдуманный способ имеет свои недостатки. В частности, способ, предложенный Sergey Nudnov, выполняет запросы insert. А это значит, что если искомая строка не будет найдена в таблице, то этот запрос добавит её. Чего в принципе быть не должно.

На самом деле, конечно, существует способ корректно сделать все апдейты одним запросом без нежелательных вставок. Запрос для этого будет и вовсе [зубодробительный](http://phpfaq.ru/safemysql/examples#complex). И, как я уже говорил, никакой прямо-таки страшной необходимости выполнять все обновления обязательно одним запросом. Десяток запросов в цикле, особенно с использованием подготовленных выраженийЙ, особенно завернутых в транзакцию ещё никому систему не обрушил.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php 
Вы про эти подготовленные выражения?

Comment: Да, именно про эти. В принципе, mysqli поже поддерживает, но настолько неудобно, что лучше сразу делать через PDO

Comment: @And PDO - это далеко не только "множество драйверов". Это почти полноценная обертка для работы с БД, со множдеством полезных функций. Рекомендую: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

Подготовьте данные в виде таблицы и используйте `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO Users (id, phone, name, surname, second_name, manager_comment, delivery_adress, delivery_time, delivery_date, courier)
VALUES
('1', '416-000-0000', 'Vasily', 'Pupkin', 'Michael', 'No comments', '123 Street', '10:00', '1 apr', 'Быстрый'),
('5', '416-000-0005', 'Сергей', 'Нуднов', 'Михайлович', 'No comments', '777 Avenue', '18:00', '1 apr', 'Супер Быстрый'),
('2', '416-000-0001', 'Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'Ivanovich', 'No comments', '345 Street', '11:00', '1 apr', 'Быстрый')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    phone=VALUES(phone),
    name=VALUES(name),
    surname=VALUES(surname),
    second_name=VALUES(second_name),
    manager_comment=VALUES(manager_comment),
    delivery_adress=VALUES(delivery_adress),
    delivery_time=VALUES(delivery_time),
    delivery_date=VALUES(delivery_date),
    courier=VALUES(courier)
```

**Подразумевается, что `id` это `Primary key`! Иначе не сработает.**

Comment: Это очень плохое решение. Автору надо не вставлять строки, а обновлять их. Это значит, что если искомая строка не найдена в таблице, вставлять строку не надо.

Comment: @Ипатьев, Решение продуктивное в случае, не динамических вложений.

Comment: @And это мина замедленного действия, которая если рванет, то мало не покажется. Запрос ON DUPLICATE может использоваться для вставки, но не должен для обновления.